# How can I render two scenes simultaneously on LibGDX?

Tags: libgdx

In my LibGDX game, I'm trying to render two 'views' (one next to the other) at the same time.

The idea is to have each view rendered according to global coordinates, but everything inside would be relative to their parent view. (e.g.: if I draw a rectangle inside View 1 and its coordinates are x=0, y=0, It would appear in the upper corner of View 1).

[image]

Comment: Have you tried rethinking your approach, would you be better to render to 2 views in their own local space, then do a final pass where you place them on your parent view.  This eliminates complexity around clipping, translation of co-ordinates etc.